# How do I check if an ngModel is visible or not through an ngIf?

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel

I want to be able to call this "threeMonth and complimentary" model as an object to find out if they are visible or not and display the last tag if they are not visible. Basically I want an if/elseif/else somehow

```
 <p  [(ngModel)]="threeMonth" name="threeMonth" *ngIf="(offers.offerAnnualIssues - offers.nssIssues) > offers.nssIssues">*3 MONTHS OF ISSUES</p>
<p [(ngModel)]="complimentary" name="complimentary" *ngIf="offers.custPrice != '2'">COMPLIMENTARY</p>
                  <p *ngIf="**If the threeMonth model is not visible and complimentary is not vivible show this**">*A FULL YEAR OF ISSUES</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ugly solution - combine the previous two if statements with nots:

```
*ngIf="!((offers.offerAnnualIssues - offers.nssIssues) > offers.nssIssues) && !(offers.custPrice != '2')"
```

Better solution - use [ngSwitch](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html) to produce cases and set the default as your last option.